Google Oauth refresh token without redirect url ? Just auto refresh
Just some context - Im creating app to merge my family calendars from different sources. I want to setup some google component but I have a problem. My code is pretty straight forward. First enter is:
    final InputStream in = DemoService.class.getResourceAsStream(this.googleConfiguration.getCredentialsPath());
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(this.jsonFactory, new InputStreamReader(in));

    final GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            this.httpTransport,
            this.jsonFactory,
            clientSecrets,
            SCOPES
    ).setDataStoreFactory(buildJpaFactory()).setAccessType("offline").build();
    final LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize(email);

Where Im able to get access token / refresh token etc. (SCOPE is CALENDAR_READONLY). Question is how do I refresh token - Im using out of the box method provided by google lib:
        return new GoogleRefreshTokenRequest(
                new NetHttpTransport(), this.jsonFactory, refreshToken, clientId, clientSecret
        ).setScopes(SCOPES).setGrantType("refresh_token").set("access_type", "offline").execute();

But the issue is that each time It ask user to log in and ask for calendar rights - How can I do silence refresh token update ? Once user accepted I just want to renew this token over and over again without asking it one more time to login and giver rights to calendar.

you shouldnt need to if your using the client id it should handle that for you
